# updating element value using java

Tags: java, xml

i have written a java code for updating the element value with the following string

```
<![CDATA[test]]>
```

but its saved in the xml file in the following manner

```
<value>&lt;![CDATA[test]]&gt;</value>
```

how to avoid these any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using DOM then you need to create a CDATA node instead of setting the block in a text node.

```
document.createCDATASection("foo");
```

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createCDATASection(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

It did exactly what you wanted. The stored data represents the String `"<![CDATA[test]]>"`!

If you use a API to create XML, just don't care for the way the XML is generated, since any parser will be able to parse it correctly. Just store the String `"test"` and be happy :).

Answer (score 0):

Use API [Document.createCDATASection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createCDATASection%28java.lang.String%29) to create the CDATA.